# How to reset your show applications menu

Tags: menu, appmenu

I installed menu-xdg on ubuntu 18.10 and now I have all the applications showing in my applications menu.

[image: Show applications menu image.]

Installing it was a mistake but now I cannot reset it to the way it was. Have tried a few methods including resetting my desktop to its default state. I can probably reset ubuntu to its default state but would prefer to have everything as it is and also want to learn from this.

Comment: I do not see the problem. It is quite normal to have all your applications in the application menu, or only your frequently used applications. At the bottom of the screen, there are buttons that allow you to swicht between these two modes.

Comment: You are not supposed to have Bash, Dash etc. there.

Comment: Clarify this in your question. Anyway, this may suggest that .desktop file were created for these apps in /usr/share/applications or ~/.local/share/applications.

Comment: None of them are in ~/.local/share/applications but thanks for the comment, it helps me dig a bit deeper.

Comment: Then they should be in /usr/share/applications if not in snap locations. The application menu is "fed" by .desktop files. Eventually, one can specify in a .desktop file that the item is not to be shown, or only to be shown in a specific desktop environment.